# Disable autostart of docker-compose project

Tags: docker-compose, autostart, docker-for-mac

I have a docker-compose project using Docker for Mac that autostarts when I boot the computer.

I usually start the project with `docker-compose up -d`, but even running `docker-compose stop` before shutting down autostarts it again on boot.

I am not aware of specifically enabling this. How can I disable it?

Comment: Can we see docker-compose file? But I'm guessing there is a `restart: always` in it. If there is, then try changing it to `restart: unless-stopped`.

Comment: Indeed, each of the services have `restart: always`. I will change it and see what happens.

Comment: That did not work. Setting `restart: unless-stopped` causes docker to time out on requests (`ps`, `stop`, `kill`). And rebooting still starts all the containers!

Comment: Not certain about `docker-compose stop`, but for me `docker-compose down` works like a charm.  I tend to pair it with `--rmi local`, but be careful with that.

Answer (score 84):

Today I had the same issue that all containers are started when I boot my dev laptop, as `restart: always` was set in the .yml files.

As I don't want to touch the .yml files, I just found out (thx Bobby) how to alter this setting by:

```
docker update --restart=no <MY-CONTAINER-ID>
```

Comment: This is also useful when you lost the `.yml`/or the project somehow :P

Comment: You can also get the current restart policy like so: `docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}' <MY-CONTAINER-ID>`

Answer (score 22):

[`restart: no`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart) is default mode. There is line inside your docker-compose file with `restart: no` or `restart: unless-stopped`. It also means that when you boot your system, it (re)starts container(s) again as long as docker daemon. [Details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart)
You need to **change `restart` to `no`** or **`on-failure`**, *example*:

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:
    backend:
        restart: on-failure
        build:
            args:
                USER_ID: ${USER_ID}
            context: codebase/namp-backend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        ports:
          - "5001:5001"
          - "5851:5851"
        volumes:
          - ./codebase/namp-backend:/codebase
        environment:
```

Also `docker-compose down` for most cases, gives you the same result - do not start containers while (docker) system startup, except: containers will be deleted after this, **not** stopped.

Comment: **no is the default restart policy**, and it does not restart a container under any circumstance. When always is specified, the container always restarts. The on-failure policy restarts a container if the exit code indicates an on-failure error.

Answer (score 18):

Try with `docker-compose down` instead of `docker-compose stop`

[down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/)

Stops containers and removes containers, networks, volumes, and images created by up.
**Networks and volumes** defined as external are **never removed**.

[stop](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/stop/)

Stops running containers without removing them. They can be started again with `docker-compose start`.

Comment: This has the unintended consequence of deleting things. The creation time from scratch is 20 mins for me, so this is not an option.

Comment: This deletes the data. In many cases could be a database, so this may not be a good solution in many cases.

Comment: The needs was just disable auto-start (restart), so if u make a `docker-compose down` will destroy all data, The best way is to as #davey said `docker update --restart=no <MY-CONTAINER-ID>`

Answer (score 14):

Use the following command if you want to disable autostart after stopping a specific container:

```
docker update --restart=no <MY-CONTAINER-ID>
```

If you want to apply this setting to all registered containers, this is the best option:

```
docker update --restart=no $(docker container ls -a -q)
```

Thank you

Comment: Other useful commands: `docker container ls -a` to check containers names & ids
and `docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}' <nameOrId>` to check their current setting

Answer (score 3):

Beside setting `restart: unless-stopped`, remove existing containers and recreate them.

```sh
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

Now, it would work as expected:

```sh
docker-compose stop
sudo service docker restart
docker-compose ps
# should NOT HAVE containers running

docker-compose up -d
sudo service docker restart
docker-compose ps
# should HAVE containers running
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to @Hudson Van-dal comment if you are really using compose. When you are in .yml compose file directory you can use:

```
docker update --restart=no $(docker compose ps -a -q)
```

It will filter out only containers running under this particular compose instead of all available containers.